# Is Broadcast Receiver what I need?

Tags: android

I’m trying to execute custom code that is invoked from a listprefeence radio box elsewhere in the setting UI.  Its code that will allow the user to select different styles of battery icons on their phone on the fly without a reboot.  I have everything done and the code executes fine with one exception.  It takes 10-12 seconds for the change to take place.  Kind of like it’s not executing until the system does its own check on battery status.  How to I get it to execute immediately upon checking the box?  Is this done through the use of a broadcast receiver?  I am trying to learn android development and have become pretty good with smali but not so much with actual Java yet.  I know it’s backwards but I’m trying….

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Jimmie

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly broadcast receiver, what you want is to find out the system service which checks on battery status. As soon as the user request is received on the UI, you can call the system service to check on battery status and subsequently change the icon.

Also the system service you are looking for may not necessarily be the battery status checker service, it might be UI updater or some other updater service which runs after some time-out and reflects your change.

So you need to figure out which system service is reflecting your change, and then manually call that system service after user has changed his preferences.

Comment: Great information, thank you. I assume I invoke the battery check service from within the same code that I used to code the radio box?  Now I just need to find out how to invoke the battery check using smali.  I am sure there is an example in the stock BatteryController.smali.

Comment: Guys, I am really sorry but I cant for the life of me figure out how to make this code execute immediately.  I cant figure out what needs to be called.